# An internal error occurred in the Places API library

Tags: google-maps, maps, cocoapods, google-places-api, google-places

I'm working with GoogleMaps an GooglePlaces API but I always obtain de same error.

"The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)"

I've tried to run pod try GoogleMaps and when I launch de project any map is loaded, only a tableView with different options.

This is my code, I only want to obtain the user position:

```
-(IBAction)getCurrentPlace:(UIButton *)sender {
[placesClient currentPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlaceLikelihoodList *placeLikelihoodList, NSError *error){
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    self.nameLabel.text = @"No current place";
    self.addressLabel.text = @"";

    if (placeLikelihoodList != nil) {
        GMSPlace *place = [[[placeLikelihoodList likelihoods] firstObject] place];
        if (place != nil) {
            self.nameLabel.text = place.name;
            self.addressLabel.text = [[place.formattedAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]
                                      componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        }
    }
}];
}
```

I have imported mi APIKEY in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MY_APIKEY"];

return YES;
}
```

And this is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target ‘googlePlace’ do

   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'GooglePlaces'

end
```

Finally, my apikey is configured to iOS application in Google Console.

What's the problem??

Answer (score 4):

This looks like your API key is either invalid or out of quota.

Can you check that you are passing the correct API key to GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(_:).

If you are sure that you are passing the correct API key check the Google API Console (https://console.developers.google.com/) to ensure you have not run over your daily quota limit.

This issue can be tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830792

Answer (score 2):

Answer my own question

https://developers.google.com/places/migrate-to-v2?hl=es-419

This fixed the problem

Migrating to Google Places API for iOS, version 2

With the version 2 release of the Google Maps SDK for iOS, the Google Places API for iOS has been split from the Google Maps SDK for iOS and is now distributed as a seperate CocoaPod.

Take the following steps to update your existing apps:

Update your Podfile to reference the GooglePlaces CocoaPod in addition to the GoogleMaps CocoaPod. If you are not using the Google Maps SDK for iOS, you can remove GoogleMaps.

If you are using the place picker, update your Podfile to reference the GooglePlacePicker CocoaPod in addition to GooglePlaces.

Rename GoogleMaps to GooglePlaces in all imports where you are using the Places API.

Specify your API key using GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(*:) instead of GMSServices.provideAPIKey(*:).

Get the required open source license text using GMSPlacesClient.openSourceLicenseInfo() as well as GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo() if you are using the Google Maps SDK for iOS or the Place Picker.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue as you are but I've come to discover that yesterday I max my request limit since this morning it worked fine. Now I'm having the issue all over again but have new API keys for both Google Maps and Google Places. Essentially I'm trying to do the same thing you were in the aforementioned example: get current location. Updating my pod doesn't work for me as I've upgraded them several times onto different versions and still this problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

After doing 8 to 12 hours R&D Found below solution. I am sure it will work.

Just add the key in AppDelegate.swift file, not any other class. It will solve your problem.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("KEY")
         GMSServices.provideAPIKey("KEY")

    }
```

**Note:** It is compulsory to initialize GMSPlacesClient in AppDelegate Because it will take some time for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

2018 answer, well in my new job, we're having a hard time about this. My own Places key works but not my new company's Places key. After a few hours, I remember the time when I was setting my own keys, I **HAD TO REFRESH or REGENERATE NEW KEYS** for the Places API before I got it to work. Now back to my current situation, I told this to my colleagues and boom, we just had to refresh the key, and it worked! :)